# Configuring static IP address in VMware running on Windows

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

I have a laptop running Windows 10. The laptop has installed VMware Workstation Player running SUSE as guest OS. In SUSE I have installed a database server (SAP HANA).

I access the database server from Windows with no problems (I have a static IP address set in SUSE (192.168.1.85) instead of using DHCP not to change the database client configurations all the time).

The problem is that all this works fine when I'm at home in the 192.168.1.x network. If I go to a different network (i.e. in the office) since Windows has a different IP address then I cannot connect to SUSE.

I tried changing the VMware Network Connection setup to `host-only` (I don't care about SUSE accessing the web, only the Windows programs) but then nothing works.

My objective is to have **only** Windows clients in my laptop access the database server (it's for development, I don't need to access the database from other machines), and the database server has to have a static IP address. How to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default there is a host-only network and it has an interface on your windows host (VMnet1).

In your virtual machine's settings change the network adapter to be host-only which uses the default VMnet1 network. Then, assign a new static IP address on your virtual machine that is not likely to be used on any other networks you connect to. i.e. 10.194.19.x (10.194.19.20)

Then, identify the VMnet1 ethernet adapter on your Windows host in control panel -> networking and assign it a different static IP address on the same subnet as your virtual machine. i.e. 10.194.19.x (10.194.19.21)

Put all other virtual machines that need to communicate on the same network (VMnet1), with a unique IP address.

All machines will be able to communicate with each other but the virtual machines will not be able to communicate outside your machine.